# Separate Woocommerce products into Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Right now in my e-commerce site, I have 2 types of digital downloadable products, a paid and a free. I'd like to separate these into different custom post types (products, and freebies).

I'd like for both to go through the add to cart/checkout process just how you would a regular product.

The problem I have now is that I have a messy list of "products" that are both paid and free products.

I'd like the freebies to live in their own admin page and obviously in their own front-end page.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You mean different product types, product is a **custom post type** that defines a property product_type which supports `simple`, `variable`, `grouped` and `external` by default in woocommerce, you may be wanting to define your own product type, check this [plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-accommodation-bookings/) that creates a product type `accommodation-booking` that is a custom product type of a `booking` defined by the [bookings extension](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/). You may also offer a bounty ;-)

Comment: @JBoulhous -  I just want to divide them up. I've done this before in regular wordpress sites with CPT, which that might not be the case here. I just want to be able to click on the sidebar of the admin page one for "products" and one for "freebies" I wasn't hoping to use another plugin so I could keep things light.

Comment: the plugin i suggest is not for using, just look at how they did it